# Buttons are aligned to center when dynamically creating the window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, wpf-controls

I am dynamically creating a window at runtime. I have custom Buttons. I need to get "Yes,No", "OK, Cancel", "OK", "Yes, No, Cancel" accordingly at runtime depending on the request.I have the pics here. 
This picture depicts, when the horizontal alignment for button is Right.I do not get both the buttons to the right. Can you please help me out in this scenario. I have also shared my code below. Problem is the Button Collection is dividing the row into the number of buttons we need.
[image: When the Horizontal Alignment is Right and buttons are resized]

My code.

```
internal sealed class MessageBoxModule : Window
{
    private static Style _ctrlButtonStyle;
    public new static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonCollectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonCollection", typeof(IList<Button>), typeof(MessageBoxModule), new PropertyMetadata(new List<Button>()));

    public MessageBoxModule()
    {
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        AllowsTransparency = true;WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        //...
    }
}

public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption)   
{
    var mbox = new MessageBoxModule();
    boxes.Add(mbox); mbox.Message = messageBoxText; mbox.Title = caption;
    switch (button)
    {
        case MessageBoxButton.OKCancel:
            mbox.ButtonCollection.Add(CreateButton(mbox, "OK"));
            mbox.ButtonCollection.Add(CreateButton(mbox, "Cancel"));
            break;
        //.... And so on.
    }
    var result = mbox.ShowDialog();
    switch (button)
    {
        case MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel://and so on.
    }
}
private static Button CreateButton(string content, bool isCancel, RoutedEventHandler clickHandler)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Padding = new Thickness(20, 3, 20, 3);
    btn.Content = content;
    btn.Style = _ctrlButtonStyle;//Custom button Style in WPF
    btn.Click += clickHandler;
    btn.Height = 25; btn.Width = 75;
    return btn;
}
```

MessageBox Style: here, the vertical and horizontal alignment is set to center. Even though I change it to right, I'm having problem like in the picture.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MessageBoxCt"
                     TargetType="{x:Type Helper:MessageBoxModule}">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                CornerRadius="3" Margin="8">
            <Grid x:Name="grid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"/>
                <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Message}"Grid.Row="1"Margin="10"TextTrimming="None"Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                           TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2"Margin="10"ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ButtonCollection}"
                              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility= "Disabled"HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"VerticalContentAlignment="Center"Padding="0,0,5,0">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `UniformGrid` each item in row takes same width and with `HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"` the button within will be right aligned. Please try `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` instead to right align the complete `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="2"
              ...
              HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard for anyone that doesn't have your code to guess what's really going on here. My guess is that your `RowDefinition`s are incorrect... why do you have one set to `"*"`? It would work better if they are *all* set to have a `Width` of `"Auto"` and if the `Grid` is set to `HorizontalAlignment="Right"`.

You could also set the [`Grid.ShowGridLines` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.showgridlines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `True` which would give you further clues as to what's *actually* happening.

To be honest though, your whole attempt seems to be wrong... this is WPF, not WinForms. You shouldn't be creating UI elements and adding them into the UI from the code behind. Your requirement is so much easier to fulfil when using WPF correctly.

First add *all* the `Button`s into the UI XAML. Next, add a `bool` property for each of them into your view model or code behind. Then, simply data bind these `bool` properties to the `Visiblity` properties of the `Button`s using a [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Now all you have to do to make each `Button` visible is to set its relevant `bool` property to `true`:

```
<Button Content="Ok" Visibility="{Binding IsOkButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource 
    BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution Sheridan. I'm new to using WPF and still learning. Setting it to HorizontalAlignment="Right" for me in this instance.